# ScrollView in a fragment inside ViewPager is not scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout, android-scrollview, android-tabs

I have a tablayout and a viewpager in an activity, inside viewpager I'm displaying a fragment with a scrollview as it's root layout, and for some reason it's not scrolling. I've been trying to make it work for hours, but nothing worked so far, please help.

This is my activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PreferencesActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_toolbar_preferences"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/prefs_title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:elevation="5dp" />
        </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And this is my fragment with scroll view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragmentsPrefsActivity.FragmentAppPrefs">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="32dp"
        android:paddingRight="32dp">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView_alerts"
            style="@style/app_prefs_cardView">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    style="@style/app_prefs_text_header"
                    android:text="Alerts"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <com.suke.widget.SwitchButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
                    app:sb_checked="true"
                    app:sb_checked_color="@color/colorPrefsDark"
                    app:sb_show_indicator="false" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:text="Sound"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_men"
            style="@style/app_prefs_description_text"
            android:text="@string/prefs_alerts_description" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView_matchMakerOnlyMode"
            style="@style/app_prefs_cardView">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.suke.widget.SwitchButton
                    android:id="@+id/switchButton"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView21"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView21"
                    app:sb_checked_color="@color/colorPrefsDark"
                    app:sb_show_indicator="false" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    style="@style/app_prefs_text_header"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="Matchmaker-Only Mode"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView21"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:text="Hide My Profile"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView10"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            style="@style/app_prefs_description_text"
            android:text="@string/prefs_match_maker_only_mode_description" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView3"
            style="@style/app_prefs_cardView">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cardView_selectLanguage"
                    style="@style/app_prefs_text_header"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="Select Language"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/language_spinner"
                    style="@style/app_prefs_text"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView_selectLanguage" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            style="@style/app_prefs_description_text"
            android:text="@string/prefs_select_language_description" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView_enableNotifications"
            style="@style/app_prefs_cardView">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView18"
                    style="@style/app_prefs_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:text="Enable notifications from GoGaga"
                    android:textColor="#151515"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_go"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btn_go" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_go"
                    style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ripple_btn_go"
                    android:text="Go"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio=""
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView19"
            style="@style/app_prefs_description_text"
            android:text="@string/prefs_enable_notification_description" />
    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try to get your ViewPager tag outside AppBarLayout
So your activity xml should be like:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
   <AppBarLayout>
      //...
   </AppBarLayout>
   <ViewPager>
      //...
   </ViewPager>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

and don't forget to add this attribute to your view pager:

```
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
```

Comment: Thanks! Thank you so much. I was trying to resolve this issue for days, trying everything on the internet. You're a true hero!